# WebMethod doesn't work on live site

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am calling a `WebMethod` function which I coded it in the availability.aspx file and I call it from javascript function this `webmethod` with the `Webservice` are working perfect on the localhost website but on the live one I got this error in the console of the browser.

> POST http://*******/*****/availability.aspx/addEvent 404 (Not Found)

What is the difference and why is not working on the live site ?

> ```
> availability.aspx
> ```

The class definition with the method

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web.Services;

public partial class driver_login_availability : System.Web.UI.Page
{


[WebMethod]
    public static int addEvent(ImproperAvailability improperEvent)
    {
        availability cevent = new availability();

        cevent.driverid = improperEvent.driverid;
        cevent.name = improperEvent.name;
        cevent.startdate = DateTime.ParseExact(improperEvent.start, "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        cevent.enddate = DateTime.ParseExact(improperEvent.end, "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        if (CheckAlphaNumeric(cevent.name))
        {
            int key = EventDAO.addEvent(cevent);
            List<int> idList = (List<int>)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["idList"];

            if (idList != null)
            {
                idList.Add(key);
            }
            return key;//return the primary key of the added cevent object
        }
        return -1;//return a negative number just to signify nothing has been added

        }
}
```

and the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

//add dialog
    $('#addDialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        theme: false,
        width: 470,
        buttons: {
            "Add": function () {

                //alert("sent:" + addStartDate.format("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt") + "==" + addStartDate.toLocaleString());
                var eventToAdd = {
                    driverid: $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_addProjectID").val(),
                    name: "Available",
                    start: addStartDate.format("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"),
                    end: addEndDate.format("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")
                };

                if (checkForSpecialChars(eventToAdd.name)) {
                    alert("please enter characters: A to Z, a to z, 0 to 9, spaces. remove any dashes or commas or apostrophes. thanks!");
                }
                else {
                    //alert("sending " + eventToAdd.title);

                    PageMethods.addEvent(eventToAdd, addSuccess, addFailure, "User Context");
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }

            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: can we see the class definition for `availability`, including any class attributes it may have?

Comment: Is the live server behind a firewall or something that might be disallowing the request?

Comment: Do Get/Post protocols available to WebServices in web.config of the live site?

Comment: @MikeCorcoran I added the class definition for you

Comment: @CodingGorilla I don't know do you think it is a security issue ?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I put them but it didn't work

Comment: @kartal It's definitely possible; your code looks fine, and works locally.  So the first thing I would do in troubleshooting is try to eliminate the possibility of external interferences (firewalls, proxies, etc) before assuming it's a code problem.

Comment: Are you by any chance making a cross domain call?

Comment: don't you have to tag the class that implements the web method as a `[WebService]` for asp to understand there are callable methods in the class?

Comment: @MikeCorcoran I tried this and also the same result

Comment: @YuriyGalanter What do you mean by cross domain call i don't know this expression ?

Comment: What us the URL of the page that makes the call and what is the URL of ASMX?

Comment: there is no asmx all the webmethod are in the same webpage availability.aspx like I mentioned in my question

Comment: it looks like your web method is expecting one param that can be serialized into an `ImproperAvailability` object. your javascript calls the method with 4 params. did you mean to wrap those params with `{...}` to group them all into one object?